# Javascript OO, issue going trough inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I've got an issue to fix with some kind of inheritance in JS.

I've set a small jsfiddle to explain, looking at:

V1
http://jsfiddle.net/FFTj4/5/

```
function Vehicule(name) ...
```

Here the result are not as expected but easily explained. I'm calling parent constructor with apply which scope the function to the "calling" object where the name is set. So far car and sportcar name are not set in their vehicule prototype so when i ask for the name and going up to vehicule name is undefined.

I fixed it with that:

V2 (uncomment v2 section in the jsfiddle)
Well now i'm also "scoping" the getName call to ensure i got my "name". I though it was fixed! So i applied the fix to SportCar also

V3 (uncomment v3 section in the jsfiddle)
Well it could not be that easy, now i'm locked SportCar call Car getName, but car is scoped to SportCar so when car "tried" to call Vehicule getName it call SPortCar getName instead, and so on, Maximum call stack size exceeded.

I need to come up with a way to be able to tu call the current object superClass, no matter if called with an apply, and of course keep the scope of the topmost object :/

I've run out of ideas, been on this for almost 2 weeks now.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

In line:

```
Car.prototype.superClass = Vehicule;
```

You are assinning function, not an instance, so you can't call

```
this.superClass.prototype.getName();
```

becouse you have no context. No object was created.
You need to do this this way:

```
this.superClass.prototype.getName.call(this);
```

Then it should work like you want :)

But, in your code it will not work becouse you are overwriting `superClass`. You need to use "class" name for this:

```
Car.prototype.getName.call(this);
```

Or just don't assign `superClass` to prototype ;)

[Here](https://github.com/Okotetto/javascript-class-inheritance/blob/master/guide-to-prototypal-inheritance-in.js.html) is a simple explanation of prototypal inheritance. Comments are in polish, but JS is JS ;)

Comment: I could but that is precisely what i don't want to do, i don't want to have to explicitly use the "parent" className to make call, like you suggested. (Car.prototype.xx), for me it should not be an issue, but dev working in my team are no js expert, it should be conveniant to use also. Like in "real" language" you just use the super keyword, no matter what it will always refer to superclass with the "child" scope.

Comment: So you need to use module pattern.
For example: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Comment: Well switching to a whole different pattern is not a solution to me to be honest. It's a good pattern, but won't be convenient to work with.

Comment: There is a lot of different ways to implement module pattern. I just gave you an example.

And also you can use jQuery or underscore.js. Thay have `extend` method for purpose like this.

Comment: I will give it a try, but so far i've not found the right pattern to achieve my goal. Using prototype is great to avoid having huge object which contain their whole" hierarchy cloned inside, but going up the chain while keeping the right scope is a pain.

Comment: If you have any questions just ask :) I'll try help you.

Comment: Thank you Sorprop, unfortunately time is against me, project must be finished today, so i've been working a lot lately and had no time to look into the module pattern. I really got a scope issue which i temporarily fixed to keep on working (not in an elegant way). Will have to fix that. I've been searching for example like mine (multiple inheritance child -> Parent -> Grand Parent -> and such) but could not find any valuable example.

Comment: I'll try think about that at weekend. It seems to be interesting problem to solve.

Comment: I can give you one more article to read about inheritance: http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html (some other explanation: http://joshgertzen.com/object-oriented-super-class-method-calling-with-javascript/)

I didn't have time for tring resolve problem, but it seems to be very big problem in JS world and there is no golden mean.